# Closure properties of familes of $G_\delta$ sets.

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, gn.general-topology, set-theory

Given a family of sets $G\subset P(X)$, can one characterize by "closure properties" alone whether or not $G$ arises as the family of all $G_\delta$ for some  topology on $X$? some Polish space topology on $X$?

Of course I'm *not* interested in the trivial answer, namely: if there exists a system of sets $T$ closed under unions and finite intersections such that every $A\in G$ is a countable intersection of sets in $T$.

I don't feel sure about the best way to bar this non-answer!  Feel free to improve my question if you have an answer.

I suppose I'm looking for something like this: (positive) statements with only universal quantifiers over combinatorially-restricted families of sets in $G$.  Combinatorially restricted can allows for restrictions on the cardinality of the family, disjointness, nestedness, etc.

This is the easiest question of this type where I don't know the answer.  So how about arbitrary levels of the Borel hierarchy?

Comment: A minor correction: your trivial answer isn't quite stated correctly, since you also need the other direction of your requirement, so that $A\in G$ if and only if $A$ is the intersection of countably many sets in $T$. 

Comment: Hmm, why can't we say that a collection of subsets $G$ is the $G_{\delta}$ if and only if the sets are closed under unions and countable intersections? If this condition is satisfied then we can let $G$ be a topology, which gives a $P$-space, i.e. the $G_{\delta}$ sets are precisely the open sets.

Comment: Gjergji, the $G_\delta$ sets in $\mathbb{R}$ include all singletons, and so are not closed under arbitrary unions. 

Comment: Ah, of course. That was silly of me.

Comment: $G_\delta$'s aren't even closed under countable disjoint unions or countable nested unions since ${\Bbb Q}$ is not $G_\delta$ in ${\Bbb R}$.